# how to influence C++ compilation order in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, compilation

OK, I should probably give a bit more context first. I'm working on a legacy C++ solution that was developed in Visual Studio 6 and because I dislike the Visual Studio 6 UI I have switched to Visual Studio 2010 with the Daffodil extension for building the legacy solution with the VC6 compiler while still working and debugging in Visual Studio 2010 (and as one more bonus, SourceSafe integration is also a lot better in Visual Studio 2010).

The solution builds fine but doesn't run and according to the old project owner this is caused by the order in which files are compiled for one of the projects. Up to now he's always been right and I've had no reason to disbelieve him. Now I think I read somewhere that there are no rules for the compilation order of files in C++ and that Visual Studio IDEs compile the files in a project based on their filename (but apparently not the Visual Studio 6 IDE), so I suffixed all of the sourcefilenames with an ascending compilation number that matches the compilation order of the file as in the Visual Studio 6 project and behold.. the compilation order still does not match that of the Visual Studio 6 project. So is there any other way of influencing this or am I going about this the wrong way? Or is the IDE actually checking the headerfilenames and not the sourcefilenames to determine the compilation order? (I was reluctant to change the headerfilenames because that will result in a lot of code changes).

PS: it is not my intention to figure out why the compilation order matters to get the program to run or how to address this, I just want to see if I can influence the compilation order in Visual Studio 2010 to prove or disprove that it matters to the end result of the compilation of this project.

**UPDATE:** maybe this is not a file initialization fiasco, *and* the project owner is wrong. I just manually compiled all files in the right order (as suggested by pwny) and ran the program and it pops up an exception messagebox for "application failed to initialize properly (0xC0000005)". It appears the program runs upto a point where an indexer is used on a nullpointer to a collection object. The associated file has a .tem file extension instead of .cpp (and the .hpp header file that is included #includes the .tem file back), it dates back from 1994 in a makefile project that fails to build on its own. The debugger refuses to show me any info when I navigate to the file from the Call Stack window. It's been a long day so I will continue tomorrow, maybe turn the makefile project into a DLL, rename the files to .cpp, get rid of the circular includes, and hope for the best.

Comment: Doubtful this is compilation order, more likely it is link order.  Google "initialization order fiasco".  If that's not it then you'll need to debug the program.

Comment: Compilation order doesn't matter: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5615463/does-g-compilation-order-matter

Comment: Also, if you really want to try a different order, you could right click on each file separately and click "Compile..." from the solution explorer.  Since it doesn't matter, I doubt it would help and you might still get link order problems down the road.

Comment: Are there any pre/post-build events in this project?

Comment: nope, no pre/post build events but the initialization order fiasco sounds like the best bet, thanks Hans. @pwny thanks for suggesting the manual compilation, takes a while for this big project but renaming files would have been way worse.

Comment: If it is an initialization ordering problem the judicious use of '#pragma init_seg(lib)' in the relevant files might help work around the issue.  Not a pretty kludge, but neither is having to work with a VS6 solution in VS2010!